# How to read an array in a python file passed from Codeigniter controller

Tags: python, codeigniter

I want to send an array from a codeigniter controller to receive in python file for further execution. I have passed the array to the python file, but I can not receive the array in python file.

**Codeigniter controller**

```py
class Aanalysis extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $postData = array(
            'hashtag' => $this->input->post('hashtag'),
            'nooftweets' => $this->input->post('nooftweets')
        );

        $output = shell_exec("python main.py" $postData);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give full path to your python file/script.
Like, `system('/full/path/to/your_python_file.py');`
If your python file exist in your apache directory where your codeigniter project exists, then you don't need to give full path.